# Choose which function to execute, based on a parameter - its name

Tags: python, python-3.3

I have different functions, but each takes different number of arguments and different arguments. I want to be able to execute only one of them and to do this based on the name of the function as string. I tried this:

```
def execute_function(function_name, arg1, arg2, arg3):
    return {
        'func1': func1(arg1),
        'func2': func2(arg1, arg3),
        'func3': func3(arg2),
    }[function_name]
```

but it executes all functions :( no matter what is the string `function_name`.

Do you have any ideas why this happens and how to achieve what I want. (I'm new to Python). Thank you very much in advance! :)

Comment: Add a default function also  with `{ .... }.get(function_name, default)()` if suppose you wrong function name pass! `default(){ print("Exception: Undefined function called..")}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add *just the functions* to the dictionary; you added their *result*.

To support variable arguments, use either lambdas or [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to wrap your functions instead:

```
def execute_function(function_name, arg1, arg2, arg3):
    return {
        'func1': lambda: func1(arg1),
        'func2': lambda: func2(arg1, arg3),
        'func3': lambda: func3(arg2),
    }[function_name]()
```

or

```
from functools import partial

def execute_function(function_name, arg1, arg2, arg3):
    return {
        'func1': partial(func1, arg1),
        'func2': partial(func2, arg1, arg3),
        'func3': partial(func3, arg2),
    }[function_name]()
```

In both cases you call the resulting object (`partial` or `lambda` function) *after* retrieving it from the dictionary.

Comment: Oooh, thank you so much! I'm ashamed now, it seems so obvious why they are all called :$ Thank you very much for removing my confusion and the solutions!

Comment: Amazing! Could you please explain a bit the first one?

Comment: @lerner: nut sure what part you are missing; each `lambda` is just a function, and each function object takes no arguments. The `arg1`, `arg2` and `arg3` values are passed into the `func1`, `func2` and `func3` calls as closures.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks very much. What confuses me most is that {..}[function_name] is the function and the () followed means its execution, then parameters should be passed through here(the last ()).

Comment: @lerner no, the lambda takes zero arguments here. Each of the wrapped functions takes a different number of arguments, after all.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, I get it, just as you said "the lambda takes zero arguments".